# Filling blanks of an excel with number above

Tags: excel

In the Amount Data attached (20k records in total) - I have two column fields ID, Amount. Below are some samples

For ID 121700, amount is 250000 and I would like to put the same amount for the the ids of 121700 whose amount are missing. Similarly for rest of the IDs. For every ID, there is an amount against that as first row and we need to keep the same amount for the below same IDs.Since there more than 9k different IDs, copy/paste or ctrl+D wont be an option. Kindly suggest

```
ID      Amount
121700  250000
121700  
121700  
121700  
122220  100000
122220  
122220  
122220  
122220  
122220  
122656  250000
122656  
122656  
122656  
122656  
122657  200000
122657  
122657  
122657  
122657  
122657
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A and B, in the first cell enter:

```
=B2
```

Then enter the following formula in the next cell (if you are entering it in  column C. Change C to any other column as required) and drag down.

```
=IF(B3<>"",B3,C2)
```

Copy and paste as values in column B again.